# Severity: Notice Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, offset, hmvc

I am getting a Severity: Notice
Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0..This is my Controller -

```
public function ManagePages()
{

  $value['page_id']=$this->uri->segment(3);
      $data['mainHeader']=$this->load->view('mainHeader');
      $data['mainnav']=$this->load->view('mainnav');
      $data['mainFooter']=$this->load->view('mainFooter');

      if($this->uri->segment(3)!=""){

      $this->load->model('MainModule');
      $value['query']=$this->MainModule->NewDataGrabber('pages','page_link',$value);
      }else{
         $value['query']='';   
      }
      $data['PageDisplay']=$this->load->view('ManagePages',$value);
      $this->load->view('projectNewView',$data);
    } 

     //my model:

public function NewDataGrabber($tbl,$field_name,$value)
{
   $this->db->where($field_name, $value['page_id']);
   $Val=$this->db->get($tbl);
   $Valreturn=$Val->row_array();
   return $Valreturn;}
```

Now My View is Look Like this :

```
enter code here     <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/Manage/<?php echo $page_id;?>" method="post">

                <?php
                if($this->session->flashdata('item')) {
                  $message = $this->session->flashdata('item');
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                          <?php echo $message['message'];?>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_error('adminemail', '<div class="alert alert-warning">', '</div>'); ?>

                    <label>Page Title</label>
                    <?php
                    if($query['page_title']==""){$query['page_title']="";}
                    ?>
                     <?php echo form_input('page_title',$query['page_title'], 'class="form-control"');?>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Keywords</label>
                      <?php echo form_input('keywords', $query['keywords'], 'class="form-control"');?>
                     <p class="help-block"></p>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Page Description</label>
                    <?php echo form_textarea('page_desc',$query['page_desc'], 'class="form-control"');?>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <?php echo form_submit('submit','Submit', 'class="btn btn-outline btn-primary"');?>

                 </div>

            </form>
```

Why i am getting this errors ..Severity: Notice .Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0..Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: keywords.. Please help me i am fresher in HMVC . Please ......

Comment: I figure it out sorry for disturbing you sir. it will need a space in

if($this->uri->segment(3)!=""){

      $this->load->model('MainModule');
      $value['query']=$this->MainModule->NewDataGrabber('pages','page_link',$value);
      }else{
         $value['query']=' ';   
      }

Comment: Hi you disturbed no one. There is noone to comment here other than you.

Comment: Yes sir my issue is fixed.